# Google Guice - Use generic as parameter of injected field

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice

I want to use a generic parameter of a class for a field that is injected, but guice complains about a unbound key. Is it possible to inject the field in Test2?

Example:

```
public static class Test1<T1> {
    }

    public static class Test2<T2> {
        @Inject
        public Test1<T2> test;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Injector injector = Jsr250.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, new TestModule());
        Test2<String> test = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Test2<String>>(){}));
    }

    private static class TestModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(new TypeLiteral<Test1<String>>(){}).toInstance(new Test1<String>());
            bind(new TypeLiteral<Test2<String>>(){}).toInstance(new Test2<String>());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is overkill for java generics. You code would not work even without injection, cuz `Test1<T2>` cannot match `Test1<String>`. You should consider different approach, try to use [Annotation binding](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) like:

```
public static class Test2 {
        @Inject @Named("T2")
        public Test1<someGenericInterface> test;
    }

bind(new TypeLiteral<Test1<someGenericInterface>>(){}).annotatedWith(Names.named("T2")).toInstance(new Test1<T2>()); //T2 implements someGenericInterface
bind(new TypeLiteral<Test1<someGenericInterface>>(){}).annotatedWith(Names.named("T1")).toInstance(new Test1<T1>()); //T1 implements someGenericInterface
```

or implement specific Provider [Provider bindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings) or use [MapBinder](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html)